# when i run "npm run watch" i'm getting this error, what does it mean and how can i solve it?

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
> crafty@1.0.0 watch /Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty
> webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch

/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:243
                                throw err;
                                ^
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'extract-text-webpack-plugin'
>           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
>           at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>           at require (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>           at Object. (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/webpack.config.js:2:25)
>           at Module._compile (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:178:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>           at require (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
>           at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:133:13)
>           at requireConfig (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:135:6)
>           at /Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:142:17
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at module.exports (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/convert-argv.js:140:15)
>           at yargs.parse (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:240:39)
>           at Object.parse (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:552:18)
>           at /Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:218:8
>           at Object. (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:515:3)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
>           at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
>           at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>           at Object. (/Users/sirishasamudrala/Desktop/crafty/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js:80:2)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! crafty@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --progress -d --config webpack.config.js --watch`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the crafty@1.0.0 watch script.npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/sirishasamudrala/.npm/_logs/2018-05-26T19_22_18_720Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

It means `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is not installed for your project.

Either run

`npm i extract-text-webpack-plugin -D`

Or

Add it to your package.json manually and run `npm i`

This usually happens when you copy paste code into your webpack config and forget to update your dependencies.

Do the same for all missing modules.